# KeyError when running df through function

Tags: python, pandas, numpy

I'm trying to apply the function below to a dataframe and return only the rows that qualify, but get an KeyError. What am I doing wrong?

```
N = 100

np.random.seed(0)

df = pd.DataFrame(
    {'X':np.random.uniform(-3,10,N),
     'Y':np.random.uniform(-3,10,N),
     'Z':np.random.uniform(-3,10,N),
    })

def func_sec(df):
    for i in range(len(df)):
        for k in range( i+1, len(df)+1 ):
            df_sum = df[i:k].sum()
            m = (df_sum>2).all() & (df_sum.sum()>10)
            return df[m]

func_sec(df)
```

Comment: What is `m = (df_sum>2).all() & (df_sum.sum()>10)` supposed to do?

Comment: Here `m` is a boolean, and your `df` does not have booleans as keys, but `X`, `Y`, and `Z`.

Comment: I'd like to return only the rows which qualify in a dataframe. I've tried to put the for loop in a function to be able to run multiple df's at once. Cannot get it to work though

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Like others have noted, the key error is thrown off because of df[m]. Your column names aren't booleans, they are 'X', 'Y', 'Z'. Somewhere at the bottom of [the pandas documentation](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/indexing.html) there is some information on boolean indexing, so i suggest you check it out.

Long story short, you can't do `df[True]`, but you *can* do `df[df['X'] > 10]` per se.

Answer (score 1):

For a dataframe `df` you can select by column e.g. 'X' in your case:

```
df['X']
```

or slice some rows

```
df[0:10]
```

If you try something invalid like `df[0]` or `df[True]` you will get a key error.